# Images as labels in a graph?

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I was wondering if there is a way to put images instead of numbers as X-axis labels in a scatter plot (or to that matter of fact, any plot) in R. I am currently using `ggplot2` but any other library will be good enough. Any suggestions?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2181902/471093

Comment: also, the vignette of grImport shows an example with lattice. I believe it could be adapted to work with ggplot2.

Comment: what kind of image? The answer would be different for:
- a vector graphic to import
- a raster graphic to import
- a glyph created from R
- a glyph function (of size, shape, colour, etc.) -- see e.g. Chernoff faces

Comment: I will look into the `grImport1 package. I am trying to import a set of raster images to substitute them as X-axis labels.

Comment: I would suggest using tikzDevice and get LaTeX to place the graphics for you. An example is at http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/38f8695ad55cc2d6?pli=1

Answer (score 2):

Look at the my.symbols function in the TeachingDemos package along with ms.image (same package) for one option using base graphics.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the suggestions. I will take a look at it today and get back.