# ggplot2: piecharts instead of points in an xy scatterplot

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

I have a four-dimensional dataset, let's call the variables x, y, z and r. There is at most one entry for each combination of x and y.
Currently, I have a scatterplot where I plot for each entry a point at position (x,y) and size z.

```
ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point(aes(size=z))
```

This produces a nice plot, but now I would like to "upgrade" it as follows: I want to replace each point with a piechart, and the piechart should be the same size as the point. The pie consists of two sections, one blue, and orange, taking up a proportion of r of the pie (r always being between 0 and 1).

Any ideas on how to do this elegantly?

Cheers

Comment: This thread should get you going: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181902/how-to-use-an-image-as-a-point-in-ggplot

Comment: I think you'll have to [write a new geom](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Creating-a-new-geom), and probably a new scale as well.

Comment: Thanks for the link John; if I just add a `stat_spoke` on top of my current graph, it does the trick nicely!

Comment: if you're willing to use base graphics instead of ggplot2 see `floating.pie` in the `plotrix` package ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick:

`ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point(aes(size=z)) + stat_spoke(aes(angle=r*2*pi, radius=3*z))`

Comment: I see how you get two dimensions from that, but it isn't a pie chart per se. I didn't see any pie chart examples at http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_spoke.html

Comment: @DavidJames You are correct, it is not a piechart. In my case, since I just wanted to express a proportion `r` for each point, the spoke is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ggforce` to realize the function, but someone has already done this for you, and created another R package called `scatterpie`, you can find it [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterpie/vignettes/scatterpie.html)