# Small ggplot2 plots placed on coordinates on a ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I would like to first use ggmap to plot a specific area with longitude and latitude as axes.

Then I would like to put small ggplot2 plots on the specific locations, given their longitude and latitude. These can be barplots with minimal theme.

My database may have the columns:

```
1. town
2. longitude
3. latitude
4. through 6. value A, B, C
```

I generate a plot (pseudocode)

```
p <- ggmap(coordinates)
```

and I have my minimal ggplot2 design

```
q<-ggplot2()+geom_bar(....)+ ... x-axis null y axis null minimal template
```

How to combine the two designs to have a ggmap with small minimal ggplot plots imposed on specific coordinates of the map?

Comment: This blog post might help... https://ikashnitsky.github.io/2017/subplots-in-maps/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one I did using pie charts as points on a scatterplot. You can use the same concept to put barcharts on a map at specific lat/long coordinates.

[R::ggplot2::geom_points: how to swap points with pie charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43984614/rggplot2geom-points-how-to-swap-points-with-pie-charts/44125392#44125392)

#### Needs further update. Some of the code used was abbreviated from another answer, which has since been deleted. If you find this answer via a search engine, drop a comment and I'll get around to fleshing it back out.

---

## Updated:

[image]

Using mostly your adapted code from your answer, but I had to update a few lines.

```
p <- ggmap(Poland) + coord_quickmap(xlim = c(13, 25), ylim = c(48.8, 55.5), expand = F)
```

This change makes a better projection and eliminates the warnings about duplicated scales.

```
df.grobs <- df %>% 
  do(subplots = ggplot(., aes(1, value, fill = component)) + 
       geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 1), 
                alpha = 0.75, colour = "white") +
       geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 1), group = component), 
                 position = position_dodge(width = 1),
                 size = 3) +
       theme_void()+ guides(fill = F)) %>% 
  mutate(subgrobs = list(annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(subplots), 
                                           x = lon-0.5, y = lat-0.5, 
                                           xmax = lon+0.5, ymax = lat+0.5)))
```

Here I explicitly specified the dodge width for your `geom_col` so I could match it with `geom_text`. I used `round(value, 1)` for the label aesthetic, and it automatically inherits the `x` and `y` aesthetics from the `subplots = ggplot(...)` call. I also manually set the size to be quite small, so the labels would fit, but then I increased the overall bounding box for each subgrob, from 0.35 to 0.5 in each direction.

```
df.grobs %>%
  {p + 
    .$subgrobs + 
    geom_text(data=df, aes(label = name), vjust = 3.5, nudge_x = 0.065, size=2) + 
    geom_col(data = df,
             aes(Inf, Inf, fill = component), 
             colour = "white")}
```

The only change I made here was for the aesthetics of the "ghost" `geom_col`. When they were set to 0,0 they weren't plotted at all since that wasn't within the x and y limits. By using Inf,Inf they're plotted at the far upper right corner, which is enough to make them invisible, but still plotted for the legend.

Comment: Thanks Brian I remade it. I have a small problem, can you help me out? I cannot place labels correctly over the labelling issue? I will place the code then you can use it as your answer, so that I can mark it as answer?

Comment: this is great, you are great!. I must learn it, tried already to put daughnuts as gauges, experimented with it... It fills the missing subplot() to a great degree. Thank you. I am sure other people will also greatly benefit from your idea.

Comment: is it possible to do the same with a line graph along the ggmap ?

Comment: @Ariel, yes, just change the code in the bigger chunk. (`geom_col` to `geom_line`, etc).

Comment: @Brian, thanks very much for illustrating this neat trick. However, as it stands the example is not reproducible, and while I have managed to get close, I am getting an error at the last step that I cannot overcome. Note that the original df from the earlier post uses columns `x1` and `y1`, not `lon`, and `lat`, and think the only issue now is in the final code chunk. If you could take a look I'd be most grateful. I've also just used the code below to generate the map `p <- ggmap(get_map(c(left = 13, right = 25, bottom = 48.8, top = 55.5)))
p<- p + coord_cartesian()`