# R - ggplot with facets: placing facets on the map

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, facet

I visualize some data using `ggplot2` package with facets. Data can be, e.g., distribution of some values over different continents (or cities, countries etc). Here are some toy data and a standard solution for making a primary plot with `facet_grid()` function.

```
    library(ggplot2)  # key library
    library(reshape2) # to convert to long format 
     databas<-read.csv(data=
    "continent,apples,bananas
    North America,30,20
    South America,15,34.5
    Europe,15,19
    Africa,5,35")
    databaslong<-melt(databas) # default conversion, will make first col.as id 
    # plotting as colored bars
    ggplot(databaslong,aes(x=variable,y=value,fill=variable))+geom_col()+facet_grid(.~continent)
```

Following is predictably produced:

[image: simple bar plot with facets]

But now I would like to have more control on the positions of facets. Particularly, it seems natural to put each on the world map onto respective positions on continents, that is some action typical for `tmap` or similar packages. For example, use native ggplot instrumentality:

```
mapWorld <- borders("world", colour="gray50", fill="gray50")
ggplot() + mapWorld
```

and to get like such (manually combined these two layers in inkscape):

[image: world map with facets]

Is it possible to achieve such a combination of ggplot and mapping packages in a programmable way?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45411140/small-ggplot2-plots-placed-on-coordinates-on-a-ggmap/45417727#45417727

Comment: Check out the `geofacet` [package](https://github.com/hafen/geofacet)