# R - Annotate a map with inset plots/graphs?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap, annotate, ggrepel

Using R, I'd like to display inset plots/graphs on a map that show profiles for specific places on the map and lines that points from the graph to the point on the map like in `ggrepel` but with plots instead of labels.

I was thinking of using `ggplot2`'s annotation of inset plots on a map also in `ggplot2` but was wondering if there were any other existing methods or better ideas/packages to use for this.

Desired maps shown below, but looking for a method with full flexibility in where the graphs go.

[Apparently they are called "pie chart symbols" or "column chart symbols" in ArcGIS.]

[image: https://underdark.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/protovis1.png?w=545]
[image: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/insights/latest/create/column-chart-symbols.htm]

Comment: With better keywords and searching, I was able to find answers on StackOverflow. 1) subgrobs as annotations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43984614/rggplot2geom-points-how-to-swap-points-with-pie-charts/44125392#44125392 2) insets with cowplot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56497958/ggplot-sf-package-how-make-simple-pie-graph-on-map?noredirect=1&lq=1 3) scatterpie https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterpie/vignettes/scatterpie.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368180/plotting-pie-graphs-on-map-in-ggplot

Comment: map-related packages https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214810/pie-charts-on-gis-maps-using-r

ggsubplot (no longer available) https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2011/10/ggplot2-for-big-data.html http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/glyph-maps.pdf https://stackoverflow.com/a/16122003/4663008 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028659/plotting-bar-charts-on-map-using-ggplot2?noredirect=1&lq=1