# Plot coloured boxes around axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider this simple example

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(x = as.factor(c('good', 'neutral', 'bad')),
       y = as.factor(c('bad', 'neutral', 'bad'))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

I would like to put the x labels (`good`, `neutral`, `bad`) in different colored boxes. For instance, `good` (on both the x and y axis) would be surrounded on a small green box, and so on.

Can I do that in `ggplot2`?

Comment: Relevant: [How to draw boxes/borders around x or y axis labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123684/how-to-draw-boxes-borders-around-x-or-y-axis-labels)

Comment: I saw it. wasnt able to get it to work in my context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution using `geom_label` outside the plot area:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label(aes(0.3, y, label = y, fill = y), hjust = 0) +
  geom_label(aes(x, 0.45, label = x, fill = x)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "none"
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, 3), ylim = c(1, 2), clip = "off")
```

[image]

---

Another solution

You should create `geom_rect` with borders, but without fill and plot them outside the plot area (using `coord_cartesian`):

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- tibble(
  x = as.factor(c('good', 'neutral', 'bad')),
  y = as.factor(c('bad', 'neutral', 'bad'))
)
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  # put rects on y-axis
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0.1, xmax = 0.45, color = y,
                ymin = as.numeric(y) - 0.1, ymax = as.numeric(y) + 0.1),
            fill = NA, size = 3) +
  # put rects on x-axis
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = 0.3, ymax = 0.4, color = x,
                xmin = as.numeric(x) - 0.15, xmax = as.numeric(x) + 0.15),
            fill = NA, size = 3) +
  # Here it's important to specify that your axis goes from 1 to max number of levels
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, 3), ylim = c(1, 2), clip = "off")
```

[image]

Comment: that looks pretty nice! but I do want a fill actually. Like the solution below. Can we do that? Also, the boxes are oversized here. Can we fit them a bit more to the text?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I added another solution

Comment: ha!!! that looks much better... except that the labels are on the plot... if we somehow avoid doing that then we have our solution!

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ added quick solution with neutral theme

Comment: thanks. I think that works. Any chance I can pick my own colors? :)

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ You can specify them with `+ scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "yellow", "pink"))`

Answer (score 6):

Like this?

```
tibble(x = as.factor(c('good', 'neutral', 'bad')),
y = as.factor(c('bad', 'neutral', 'bad'))) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = c('red', 'blue', 'green')))
```

Your Plot:

[image: your Plot]

### EDIT

An alternate pretty Ghetto solution using `grid`

```r
tibble(x = as.factor(c('good', 'neutral', 'bad')),
y = as.factor(c('bad', 'neutral', 'bad'))) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point()

grid::grid.polygon(x = c(.3,.3,.25,.25), y = c(.07,.04,.04,.07),gp = gpar(col = 'green', fill = 'green', alpha = .5))
grid::grid.polygon(x = c(.525,.525,.575,.575), y = c(.07,.04,.04,.07),gp = gpar(col = 'red', fill = 'red', alpha = .5))
grid::grid.polygon(x = c(.79,.79,.86,.86), y = c(.07,.04,.04,.07),gp = gpar(col = 'blue', fill = 'blue', alpha = .5))
```

[image: the Ghetto way]

Comment: yes, very close! except that instead of coloring the letters, I would like to have a small colored box around each label. Say a red box for bad, a green for good, a whie for neutral

Comment: We re almost there. Just looking for labels very much like the background `spec_color` in `kable` http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html

Comment: thanks! pretty interesting but I do not understand the `grid` step here

Comment: for instance, how could I also get the colored boxes on the y axis?

Comment: Yes, you could.
Grid 'understands' the whole plot output as a graphic, without using the axis. 
X- and Y-coordinates are the absolute places of the axis labels, so you only have to play around with them a little, until your boxes cover your y-labels.
It is comparable to finishing your plot and drawing onto it using MS Paint;)

Answer (score 2):

**Another approach**

Create a vector of colors and pass them into `axis.text.x()` option of `theme()`.

```
# data
x = as.factor(c('good', 'neutral', 'bad'))
y = as.factor(c('bad', 'neutral', 'bad'))
df<- data.frame(x,y)

# create a vector of colors
mycolors<- c("red","blue","green")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = mycolors))
```

[image: axis-labels]

Comment: same comment as below. We re almost there. Just looking for labels very much like the background `spec_color` in `kable` http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ have you seen these related posts, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123684/how-to-draw-boxes-borders-around-x-or-y-axis-labels), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31370587/how-can-you-create-a-box-around-an-axis-tick-label-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be this:

```
tibble(x = as.factor(c('good', 'neutral', 'bad')),
       y = as.factor(c('bad', 'neutral', 'bad'))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=0.5, xmax=1.5, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf), fill="red", alpha=0.1)+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=1.5, xmax=2.5, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf), fill="yellow", alpha=0.1)+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=2.5, xmax=3.5, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf), fill="green", alpha=0.1)
```

With `geom_rect()` you can add colored backgrounds:

[image]

Comment: ah ! thanks but I mean just the label. say, `bad` is enclosed in a red box but this happens only on the axis. As if we just wanted to have colors for the axis labels, but this time we surround the label (good, bad, neutral) with a tiny colored box instead of coloring the text. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I don't know how I can put the labels into a colored box. But you can adapt the color of the label text: `+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color=c("red","yellow","green")),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color=c("orange","blue")))`