# users own pch (clip) in r

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, pch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use an image as a point in ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181902/how-to-use-an-image-as-a-point-in-ggplot)

Is it possible to have user defined pch (clip art or icon or other type of file) used as point in R base or ggplot or other graphical device.

For example:

[image]

```
set.seed(123)
mydt <- data.frame (x = rnorm(5, 5,2), y = rnorm (5,10,3), z = rnorm (5, 1,0.5))
```

[image]

Here size is proportional to z.

Comment: grImport seems interesting, I am interested to see how this can be used in this situation !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `grid.raster`

```
library(png)
flower <- readPNG("flower.png")
pushViewport(plotViewport(margins=c(5,5,5,5)))
grid.rect(gp = gpar(fill=NA))
pushViewport(plotViewport(margins=c(5,5,5,5),
                          xscale=extendrange(mydt$x),
                          yscale=extendrange(mydt$y)))


grid.raster(image=flower,x=mydt$x,y=mydt$y,width=mydt$z, 
                interpolate=FALSE,default.units = 'native')
grid.polyline(mydt$x,mydt$y,default.units='native')
upViewport(2)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks agstudy for the solution, it seems a easier alternative to grImport (i am just struggling to understand)

Comment: actually I would like to display axis label, the example I provided was hand drawn, I forgot to mention it

Comment: Type grid.axis() before grid.raster line. i am far from a pc to do it.

Answer (score 3):

For Base graphics look at the `my.symbols` and `ms.image` functions in the TeachingDemos package.