# pictorial chart in r

Tags: r, graph, plot, image, figure

I am trying to develop pictorial charts. Is it possible to develop such charts in R ?
[image]

```
 myd <- data.frame (categories = c("Planes", "Ships", "Cars", "Trains"), 
values = c(15, 18, 22, 11))
```

Component icons are here:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's certainly *possible* but it will probably take considerable work.  Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181902/how-to-use-an-image-as-a-point-in-ggplot and also look at `multsymbolbox` in the `plotrix` package

Comment: This sort of diagram flunks the Tufte test.  Too much ink for too little info.  Worse, it's difficult to tell whether one car, e.g., is worth more than one train.

Comment: true may be good in science journal, but still may be useful in house / parliament floor, business meeting or general public meetings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hope that this would be helpful four your house / parliament floor

Edit: I forget to mention my [reference](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-1/RJournal_2011-1_Murrell.pdf) and I add some explanations.
[image]

```
library(lattice)
library(grid)


imgs.names <- c('WNinq','7dqJM','9E3Wj','tStmx')
library(png)
images <- lapply(imgs.names, function(x) 
     readPNG(paste(mypath,x,'.png',sep=''),native=TRUE))
## I generate some data because we don't give a reproducible example
x <- c(rep(0,4),rep(10,9),rep(20,3),rep(5,8),rep(4,8),rep(15,4),rep(13,8))
barchart(1:4~x, origin=0, col="yellow",xlim=c(0,30),
             xlab ='values',ylab='categories',title = 'Pictorial',
             scales = list(
               y = list(cex=2,col='blue', at = 1:4,labels = c('Trains','Cars','Ships','Planes')),
               x = list(cex=2,col='blue',at=seq(0,30,by=10))
               ),
             panel=function(x, y, ...) {
                panel.fill(col = rgb(1,1,205/255))    ## I had to pick up the same yellow color!!
                panel.grid()
                lapply(1:4,function(id){
                grid.raster(images[[id]], x=x[which(y==id)],  y=y[which(y==id)],
                           default.units="native",
                           just="left",
                           width =unit(2, "native"),
                           height=unit(0.7, "native"))
                }
            )
          }
         )
```

Comment: @shNIL I am surprised  that they ask for such diagram!