# How to make custom plot symbols from vector graphics in R

Tags: r, graphics, plot

Is there some way how to make custom points in R? I am familiar with `pch` argument where are many choices, but what if I need to plot for example tree silhouettes?
**For example if I draw some point as eps. (or similar) file, can I use it in R?**. Solution by raster is not good in the case of complicated objects (f.e. trees).

[image]

Comment: Hi @docendodiscimus!. I do not think it is a duplicate question. I have edited the question. Hope the image clearly explain why the raster solution is not working.

Comment: You haven't explicitly asked for non-`ggplot` solutions. If you can consider `ggplot`, have a look [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637455/is-it-possible-to-display-custom-image-say-png-format-as-geom-point-in-r-ggplo). Also check the suggestion in the comments by me and @joran.

Comment: I think this can be done with the `grImport` package, at least for .ps files. You can find some examples [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grImport/vignettes/import.pdf), check Figure 8..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with the `grImport` package. I drew a spiral in Inkscape and saved it as `drawing.ps`. Following the steps outlined in the grImport [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grImport/vignettes/import.pdf), we trace the file and read it as a sort of polygon.

```
setwd('~/R/')
library(grImport)
library(lattice)

PostScriptTrace("drawing.ps") # creates .xml in the working directory
spiral <- readPicture("drawing.ps.xml")
```

The vignette uses lattice to plot the symbols. You can also use base graphics, although a conversion is needed from device to plot coordinates.

```
# generate random data
x = runif(n = 10, min = 1, max = 10)
y = runif(n = 10, min = 1, max = 10)

# lattice (as in the vignette)
x11()
xyplot(y~x,
       xlab = "x", ylab = "y",
       panel = function(x, y) {
        grid.symbols(spiral, x, y, units = "native", size = unit(10, "mm"))
        })

# base graphics
x11()
plot(x, y, pty = 's', type = 'n', xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = c(0, 10))
xx = grconvertX(x = x, from = 'user', to = 'ndc')
yy = grconvertY(y = y, from = 'user', to = 'ndc')
grid.symbols(spiral, x = xx, y = yy, size = 0.05)
```

[image]