# Replace point shapes in ggplot2 scatter plot with images

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a scatter plot with customized point shapes. For various reasons I would like to replace the standard point shapes in ggplot2 scatter plot with shapes that don't exist in the standard ggplot2 shape set.

I understand the general principle of changing shapes in a scatter plot but I would like to know if it is even possible to import an image (SVG, png, jpg, etc) and then use it in ggplot2.

So if this was my plot:

```
mtcars
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg)) + geom_point(shape=12)
```

How would I replace the shape with an image (import it, make it available to ggplot2, reference it in geom_point).

Note that a previous post has addressed this issue but it is in my opinion unclear what the author meant; the links are broken and there isn't code that would clarify this matter. Here is the old post regarding this issue for your reference:

[How to use an image as a point in ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181902/how-to-use-an-image-as-a-point-in-ggplot)

Thanks. In case anyone is interested, the shape I am trying to enter is a little person (stick figure, think xkcd)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637455/is-it-possible-to-display-custom-image-say-png-format-as-geom-point-in-r-ggplo might help for a quick (but not perfect) way

Comment: @user20650 that link looks promising. I completely missed that.