# Is it possible to add custom shapes ( from png) to ggplot legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, ggimage

I was wondering whether it is possible to add shapes to the legend for `ggimage()`. I found similar questions, but  they either have 1) same picture with a different color in legend, or 2) same picture different colors. I used [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61327081/how-to-use-an-image-as-a-legend-key-glyph/61333337?noredirect=1#comment108607750_61333337) to add images to the legend that have color, but i can't figure out how to edit it so that image will be different. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36133374/custom-legend-with-imported-images), but I am not advance enough to adjust the code to fit my case

```
d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10),
                y = rnorm(10),
                image = sample(c("https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png",
                                 "https://jeroenooms.github.io/images/frink.png"),
                               size=10, replace = TRUE)
)

ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_image(aes(image=image, color=image), size=.05)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom legend with imported images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36133374/custom-legend-with-imported-images)

Comment: Hi, thanks, almost! But it does not produce the desired color.

Comment: I want to change a shape of a color in legend to the image, so 9instead of circle there would be an image, but I would like to preserve color in legend

Comment: One shape can be used changing the underlying draw_key function like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61333337/7941188. This does not allow modification of shape by group though.

Comment: yes, I saw it, but again, this not what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Solved by ussing `ggdraw`:
`p2` os the `ggplot()` object where I ploted images in row (coordinates x=2, y = c(1,2) ) and added text (coordinates x=2.5, y=c(1,2))

```
ggdraw() +
  draw_plot(p1) +
  draw_plot(p2, x = 0.55, y = 0.6)
```

And then I just play around with the position of p2 as well as added xlim and ylim to p2 to make text and image together