# How can we use the custom images in ggplotly to represent a point?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

For example, using the `longley` dataset in R, we can plot using

```
p <- ggplot(longley , aes(Year, Population, frame = Year)) + geom_point()
```

To animate it we can use

`Out <- ggplotly(p, height = 600, width = 600) %>% animation_opts(frame = 1120, easing = "linear")`

Is there a way to replace that black dot with an image, let's say R logo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/27637455/3358272

Comment: @r2evans I am trying to _animate_ the plot and I am unable to use an image as a point when I do so.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use plotly.