# Visualize quantities by icons using R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking for a R package in order to visualize quantities and shares using icons. For instance, 21 female and 4 male participants in a study could be visualized by 21 female icons and 4 male icon aligned in one line or across five lines like in this figure.

[image]

So far I've tried to use the `icons` library which enables the use of `fontawesome` icons. However this icons cannot be plotted in a loop. See https://github.com/mitchelloharawild/icons

Comment: I'm voting to close as off-topic, since questions shouldn't just be about package recommendations. However, you can do this with the waffle package

Comment: I described a clear problem to be solved in R and I reported what ways I have already tried to solve the problem. This is not off-topic. The waffle package is a valid answer. Thanks.

Comment: For me this is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181902/how-to-use-an-image-as-a-point-in-ggplot because the images are not placed randomly arround the plane but arranged in a so called waffle plot.

Comment: Maybe if there were some code it wouldn't be just a rec question, but right now you're essentially saying "I want to make something like this figure" and then asking for a package to do that. Help section: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Whats wrong about asking for an efficient way to solve a specified problem? I thought a package could exist but I did not exclude code solutions.  
I do not see that a question like this could attract opinionated answers.

Answer (score 2):

There is the package `ggwaffle` which can be installed as following:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("liamgilbey/ggwaffle")
```

Then you can do:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggwaffle)
library(emojifont)

data <- tibble(dog = rep("a", 4) %>% c(rep("b", 21)))
waffle_data <- waffle_iron(data, aes_d(group = dog), rows = 5) %>% mutate(label = fontawesome('fa-paw'))

ggplot(waffle_data, aes(x, y, color = group)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=label), family='fontawesome-webfont', size=4) +
  coord_equal() + 
  theme_waffle()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way:

```
library(xtable)
library(fontawesome)
library(htmltools)

dat <- data.frame(
  c(
    fa("dog", width = "2em", height = "2em"), 
    fa("cat", width = "2em", height = "2em")
  ),
  c(
    fa("dog", width = "2em", height = "2em"), 
    fa("cat", width = "2em", height = "2em", fill = "red")
  )
)

tbl <- print(xtable(dat), type = "html", 
             sanitize.text.function = function(x) x,
             include.rownames = FALSE,
             include.colnames = FALSE,
             print.results = FALSE)

browsable(HTML(tbl))
```

[image]