# How to use images as the "shape" of the points in a graph in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, factoextra

I'm making a graph of a PCA in R using morphological data of distinct fishes and I'm using the package "factoextra" to make this plot. I runned the following code:

```
fviz_pca_ind(pca, axes = c(1:2), geom.ind = "point", pointshape = 21, 
             pointsize = 2, 
             fill.ind = data$spp, 
             col.ind = "black", 
             palette = "jco", 
             addEllipses = TRUE,
             label = "var",
             col.var = "black",
             repel = TRUE,
             legend.title = "Species") +
  ggtitle("") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Which had returned me the following graph:

[image: Principal Component Analysis of Clueiformes morphology]

My goal is to ill the clusters and the index of the graph with images of the respective fish specie instead of these colored points (These images are png's that I already have in my PC). How can I make it?

Comment: OP, you can check [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181902/how-to-use-an-image-as-a-point-in-ggplot) as a good reference.  I would have tagged this as a duplicate of that, but none of the 3 answers are accepted.  All present viable methods to show an image in the plot - my recomendation would be to use `ggimage` and `geom_image()`.

Comment: Where are you trying to put the pictures, at the centroid of each cluster? Do you already have those points, or do you need a way to extract them? Regardless, I have a feeling this will become pretty cluttered & hard to read